# DataWeave transform message two arrays with numbers

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb

I would like compare two arrays (like `input2`) with numbers. And If the price is different about 5% increase, then I would like send email. I tried like this but it gave only the number that matches the same numbers. But I would like have only this price that it's increase 5% more.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json 

var input2 = [{
            "T": "GIK",
            "c": 10.02
       
        },
        {
            "T": "EXTR",
            "c": 4.43
          
        },
        {
            "T": "TANH",
            "c": 2.34
          
        },
        {
            "T": "VSAT",
            "c": 34.24
          
        },
        {
            "T": "KIMpL",
            "c": 25.9102
            
        }]
---
payload.results.c reduce (item, acc = []) -> if (input2.c contains item) acc + item else acc
```

Comment: The question is not fully clear which can cause answers not exactly being what you need. Please provide input payload, expected output, confirm that the prices are attribute "c", and if you expect the other attributes to match to compare the prices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from your script that you want the numbers (attribute c of input2 elements) that deviate a percentage from same attribute c from the payload. If you just need to compare the percentage from every number to every number in the other array this script does it. I used a function to calculate the percentage difference.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json 
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var maxPercentageDifference=5
fun percentageDifference(a,b)=abs(a-b)/((a+b)/2)*100
var input2 = [
    {
        "T": "GIK",
        "c": 10.02
    
    },
    {
        "T": "EXTR",
        "c": 4.43
    },
    {
        "T": "TANH",
        "c": 2.34       
    },
    {
        "T": "VSAT",
        "c": 34.24
    },
    {
        "T": "KIMpL",
        "c": 25.9102
    }
]
---
payload.results.c 
    reduce (item, acc = []) -> if (input2.c some (percentageDifference(item, $) <= maxPercentageDifference)) acc + item else acc
```

Input:

```json
{
    "results": [
        {
            "T": "GIK",
            "c": 10.05

        },
        {
            "T": "EXTR",
            "c": 4.41
        
        },
        {
            "T": "TANH",
            "c": 8
        
        },
        {
            "T": "VSAT",
            "c": 44
        
        },
        {
            "T": "KIMpL",
            "c": 25.9102
            
        }
    ]
}
```

Output:

```
[
  10.05,
  4.41,
  25.9102
]
```

However if you want to match the ids in attribute "T" before comparing the values, just change above script's body to:

```js
payload.results 
    filter ((item, index) ->  percentageDifference((input2 firstWith($.T == item.T)).c, item.c) <= maxPercentageDifference )
```

New Output:

```json
[
  {
    "T": "GIK",
    "c": 10.05
  },
  {
    "T": "EXTR",
    "c": 4.41
  },
  {
    "T": "KIMpL",
    "c": 25.9102
  }
]
```